# Solution to a mutiple choice question based on continuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let$f:R\mapsto R$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in R$, we have,

$\int_{0}^{1}f(xt)dx=0$ (*)then,

A) There is an $f$ satisfying (*) that takes both positive and negative values.

B) There is an $f$ satisfying (*) that is zero at infinitely many points, but not identically zero

C) $f$ must be identically zero on the whole of R.

D) There is an $f$ satisfying (*) that is identically zero  on $(0,1)$ but not identically zero on the whole $R$

My attempt:

Consider,
$\int_{0}^{1}f(xt)dx=0$

Substituting $xt$=$y$ we get

$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{f(y)}{t}dy=0$

Differentiating both the sides w.r.t to $t$ ,

$f(t)=0$

$\implies$ there exists $f$ that is identically $0$? Is this even correct?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307726/42969

Comment: Thank you Martin R that helped me!